# Querying array index using $elemMatch

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My collection is structured as following,

```
"data":[ 
        [ 
            ISODate("2018-10-01T03:45:00.000Z"), 
            752.5, 
            752.9, 
            746.5, 
            746.5, 
        ], 
        [ 
            ISODate("2018-10-02T03:46:00.000Z"), 
            746.5, 
            750.9, 
            746.5, 
            749.95, 
        ],...
     ]
```

How do I query the collection so that only those sub-arrays of "data" array are returned where element at certain index matches certain condition.

For example, to find arrays where element at index 1 is greater than "750",

```
db.collections('mycol').find({
            "data":
            {
                "$elemMatch":
                {
                    "$.[1]":
                    {
                        "$gte": 750
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Clearly this wouldn't work because "$.[1]" is not right way to specify index 1, so what should I replace it with ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "data": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$data",
          as: "d",
          cond: {
            $gte: [
              { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$d", 1] },
              750
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

This solution finally worked for me. It gives out all the matching nested sub arrays.

**Explanation**

*$addFields* is used for adding a field in output, however we can also use it to OVERWRITE an existing field which would be in the output. So since the *data* field in output will contain all the arrays, we then replace *data* field with a new *data* field which only contains arrays that match the given criteria.

*$filter* is used for this purpose, from given set of arrays it will only return those arrays which satisfy the criteria described in *cond* parameter.

Since the array does not have any identifier/key, we use *$arrayElemAt* to obtain value present at given index in the array and then use our regular query parameters for conditional filtering. After doing this only those arrays are returned which satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 2):

One way to get this and match on specific index (in this case `1`) would be:

```
db.collection.find({
  "data": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "1": {
        "$gte": 750
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  "data.$": 1
})
```

See it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8szRFQ3IlvC)

If you do not care about the index and you just want to check if values there are bigger than `750`:

```
db.collection.find({
  "data": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "$gte": 750
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  "data.$": 1
})
```

See this one [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0-XKRBF30-M)

To get multiple use aggregation since with $elemMatch you can not get multiple values:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "data": {
        $gte: 740
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: How do I obtain multiple arrays which satisfy the query conditions ?

Comment: I have a very close problem but I need to use $convert operator to make numerical comparison b/c I have value stored as a string. How can I do that?